# how to get an object position relative to primary screen

Tags: c#

In C#, how can I get an object's position in form relative to primary screen?

I searched a little but I got really confused.

I get the form location and object location and summed but it wasn't correct:

```
X = this.Location.X + pictureBox1.Location.X;
Y = this.Location.Y + pictureBox1.Location.Y;
```

I also tried this:

```
mypoint = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
```

and this:

```
mypoint =new Point(this.Location.X + pictureBox1.Location.X - Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Left,
          this.Location.Y + pictureBox1.Location.Y - Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Top);
```

I want the pictruebox1 location related to display point(0,0).
[image]

Comment: pictureBox1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty); this should be a correct solution. Why do you know it return incorrect result?

Comment: yes you are right, my mistake! I don't know why but I used form location changed event handler it gave me wrong location  at startup, I used form load and it works Fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pictureBox1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);` is the correct solution. You get it wrong from the location changed event handler maybe it is raised before the form is completely loaded.